# Set Canvas strokeStyle color from a CSS property?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, canvas

In our Angular2 / Ionic 2 project we have a HTML Canvas element that can be drawn on. **How can I set the Canvas strokeStyle property using a color provided by a CSS style?**

Below is a snippet of the draw function. Is it possible to set the `context.strokeStyle` property to a value retrieved from CSS?

```
draw = function () {
            context.clearRect(0, 0, self.canvas.nativeElement.width, self.canvas.nativeElement.height);
            context.strokeStyle = "#000";
            context.lineJoin = "round";
            context.lineWidth = 5;
            for (var i = 0; i < clickX.length; i++) {
                context.beginPath();
                if (clickDrag[i] && i) {
                    context.moveTo(clickX[i - 1], clickY[i - 1]);
                } else {
                    context.moveTo(clickX[i] - 1, clickY[i]);
                }
                context.lineTo(clickX[i], clickY[i]);
                context.closePath();
                context.stroke();
            }
            self.canvasEmpty.emit(self.isCanvasEmpty());
        },
```

My original thought was to assign a CSS class to the `canvas` tag with the `color` property set. Then I would retrieve the value of the `color` property from `self.canvas.nativeElement`. However, no CSS styles are available when I inspect `self.canvas.nativeElement` using Chrome Web Inspector tools.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In general, you can attach the style or class to an element which is temporarily inserted to DOM and then use `getComputedStyle()` for the `color` property to get a string which can be used with `stokeStyle` in 2D context.

Any should do as `strokeStyle` [do take a CSS color](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/strokeStyle#Options):

> A DOMString parsed as CSS  value.

Note that `color` can return the value `transparent` which you may want to handle separately.

### Example

Below is an example on how to retrieve the color value based on a class-name. The element is inserted into DOM because some browsers require it in order to calculate the CSS property values.

Change the color in the CSS class to change the color for the arc drawn in canvas.

```js
var ctx = document.querySelector("canvas").getContext("2d");

function colorFromCSSClass(className) {
  var tmp = document.createElement("div"), color;
  tmp.style.cssText = "position:fixed;left:-100px;top:-100px;width:1px;height:1px";
  tmp.className = className;
  document.body.appendChild(tmp);  // required in some browsers
  color = getComputedStyle(tmp).getPropertyValue("color");
  document.body.removeChild(tmp);
  return color
}

// alter color in style-sheet to alter stroke color
ctx.strokeStyle = colorFromCSSClass("myStyle");
ctx.lineWidth = 5;
ctx.arc(150, 75, 70, 0, 6.28);
ctx.stroke();
```

```css
/* Alter color here to alter stroke color in canvas */
.myStyle {
  color:#09f;
  }
```

```html
<canvas></canvas>
```

Comment: Works great! Great tip on the transparent color. That may happen since we are building our application with theming in mind. I will add a conditional check for handling transparent. Thank you for the assistance.